# How can I test a old SSD disk in my home?

Tags: ssd, malware-detection

I need to access my old SSD to recover some archives and personal data. The drive didn't work well so I decided to replace it with a new one.

I don't know what was wrong with it or if it was infected with malware, which is why I want to test it properly.

Maybe I could use a virtual machine or sonething. I do not have a test machine or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

> The drive didn't work well so I decided to replace it with a new one.

You can use your existing computer to test the old drive. It may have errors on it if not working well.

First find the disk test app for the old SSD and make a bootable USB of the App. The site may have this or use Rufus to make the USB bootable.

Remove the new SSD, install the old SSD, and the boot with the disk test App and test the old SSD.

You can also put Malwarebytes on a USB and test the disk for malware.

Once you have tested it, and if it tests OK, then get a USB carrier for it, reinstall the new SSD and recover files.

Be sure to test first for viruses in any files.

Comment: Addressing the concern with malware would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 10/11, you already have a safe virtual machine
which is ready-made :
[Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-isolation/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview).

The Sandbox is a Windows environment that is discarded whenever it's
closed and is totally isolated from the rest of Windows.
This means that even if the disk carries infected files, the virus
cannot infect your everyday Windows setup.

Run Windows Sandbox by entering `Windows Sandbox` in the Start menu.
It will look exactly like a fresh Windows desktop and behave the
same way.
Anything you do within this new window will be discarded when you close it.

Comment: The implied question, I guess, is how safe is connecting a drive with unknown (possibly malicious) content.

Comment: @gronostaj: The answer is : Not very safe, especially if one wants to examine the contents of one or more files, even innocent images or document files.

Answer (score 0):

> The drive didn't work well so I decided to replace it with a new one.

This isn't very specific. If you mean the drive itself possibly was having issues, I'd treat it as a data recovery case and check the drive's SMART status then depending on findings image / clone the drive. As a final step you can try mount the disk image and recover files or use data recovery software to extract files. Only for the last option you may need to purchase a license.

I'll try use as little tools as possible.

**Download:**

- DMDE from https://www.dmde.com
- OFSMount from https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

**Check SMART status**

Start DMDE > Select physical drive > Click Parameters > select Additional TAB > Click SMART.

If Reallocated Sectors Count and Current Pending Sectors Count both display 0 (zero) in the RAW column proceed to next step

**Clone/Image the drive**

For this you need a volume with enough free space to store the image file. The image file size will equal the size of the source drive.

Start DMDE > Select the physical drive > click Copy Sectors > In dialog select the source drive and accept defaults > for destination click File > select the drive where you will write the image file ([video](https://youtu.be/32GJr39O744)).

**Mount image file**

Run OFSMount > click Mount new > select image file > follow steps of the wizard.

As end result the drive will be assigned a drive letter. If you're worried about malware do not execute any programs from the drive. Only copy user data like your photos and such. Check recovered files with your virus scanner.

**File Recovery**

In case the file system is corrupt you may not be able to mount the disk image file. you'll then have to resort to file recovery software like DMDE.

Run DMDE > Select the physical drive > Select your partition and click 'Open Volume. 9 out of 10 times DMDE will show the directory structure and your files. If there's too much file system corruption you will be prompted ton run a full scan.

The free version only allows for recovery of one folder AND maximum 4000 files. You can repeat running the software as many times as you like and recover more files, however a $20 license removes the restrictions.

If you're worried about malware check recovered files with your virus scanner.